# Vim find integers in file

Tags: regex, vim

I want to search for all integers in a file inside Vim session only without having to worry about the number of digits in the integers.
Sample file below.

```
aekv 27bc1 97 print
 uint32 genid;
1hd solo 20941 h1xl
1
lev 87; rex
8h fp0 4U 2
```

Search should put cursor at start of any of the below integers only:

```
97
20941
1
87
2
```

`/\<[0-9]` helps with words starting with a digit alright.
But beyond that I am add mode to search for integers with any number of digits, I have tried with multiple combinations of `\w`, `\d`, etc.

Note: This is a precursor action for a substitute operation that adds a suffix `U` to all integers, so that they are treated as unsigned integers.

Comment: `:help \w` is irrelevant. `:help \d` is only relevant if you find `[0-9]` too verbose. Atom quantifiers are described under `:help pattern-multi-items`.

Comment: perhaps `\<\d\+\>`?

Comment: @Nick This worked fine! May be post it as an answer so I can mark it?

Comment: ... as for your `:substitute` operation, you probably want to look into `:help s/\&` to do `&U`

Comment: @Friedrich Did that already :)

Comment: @c10 answer posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex to find strings of only digits in your file:

```
\<\d\+\>
```

This matches:

- `\<` : a left word boundary
- `\d\+` : one or more digits - note that in vim regex `+` (one or more) must be preceded by `\`
- `\>` : a right word boundary